# why does the toggle load in checked state, even though I have set checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}". Packed__c is a checkbox woth default value false

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, slds, lightining

Please find the code below:

**App--**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
    <aura:attribute name = "item" type = "Camping_Item__c" default ="{**'Packed__c':'false'**}"/>
    
    <c:campingListItem item= "{!v.item}"/>
</aura:application>
```

**CMP--**

------ campingListItem.cmp         ----------------------------------

```
<aura:component  >   
    <aura:attribute name = "item" type = "Camping_Item__c" required = "true"/>
    <p>**{!v.item.Packed__c}**</p>
    <p>
            <lightning:input type="toggle"
                             label="Packed?"
                             name="packed"
                             class="slds-p-around_small"
                             **checked="{!v.item.Packed__c}"**
                             messageToggleActive="Yes"
                             messageToggleInactive="No"
                             />
    </p> 
    <p> <lightning:button 
                         label="Packed!"
                         name="packed"
                         onclick="{!c.packItem}"
                         />
    </p>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller--**

----------campingListItemController.js----------------------

```
({
    packItem : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.item.Packed__c","true");
        var button = event.getSource();
        button.set("v.disabled",true);
        
    }
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, we have [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. The string `"false"` is actually a truthy value. In simple terms, `'false' != false`. To get a false value, do not enclose the value in quotes.

```
<aura:attribute name="item" type="Camping_Item__c" default="{'Packed__c':false}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @sfdcfox. I am a beginner, couldn't think of this even after so much brain stroming. You saved the day!